# How To Disable "The document being saved contains tracked changes" Word Dialog Using C#

Tags: c#, .net, ms-office

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ApplicationClass msDoc = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ApplicationClass();
msDoc.Visible = false;
msDoc.Application.Visible = false;
msDoc.Documents.Open(ref docPath, ref UNKNOWN,
                     ref READ_ONLY, ref UNKNOWN, ref UNKNOWN,
                     ref UNKNOWN, ref UNKNOWN, ref UNKNOWN,
                     ref UNKNOWN, ref UNKNOWN, ref UNKNOWN,
                     ref UNKNOWN, ref UNKNOWN, ref UNKNOWN, ref UNKNOWN, ref UNKNOWN);
msDoc.WindowState = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdWindowState.wdWindowStateMinimize;
object format = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdSaveFormat.wdFormatPDF;
msDoc.ActiveDocument.SaveAs(ref target, ref format,
                            ref UNKNOWN, ref UNKNOWN, ref UNKNOWN,
                            ref UNKNOWN, ref UNKNOWN, ref UNKNOWN,
                            ref UNKNOWN, ref UNKNOWN, ref UNKNOWN,
                            ref UNKNOWN, ref UNKNOWN, ref UNKNOWN,
                            ref UNKNOWN, ref UNKNOWN);
```

The problem is that when SaveAs is executed a dialog appears. I'm trying to disable that dialog programmatically so that the user never has to provide input or configuration of Office/Word. The utility I'm writing could potentially have 100s of saves so a pop-up dialog isn't good.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I was able to figure out a programmatic solution by setting the following option in my code:

```
msDoc.Application.Options.WarnBeforeSavingPrintingSendingMarkup = false;
```

Configuration wise I found you could also disable this Office feature by going into:

Word Options->Trust Center->Privacy Options->Uncheck "Warn before printing, saving or sending a file that contains tracked changes or comments"

Answer (score 2):

```
msDoc.Options.WarnBeforeSavingPrintingSendingMarkup = false;
```

or

Word Options->Trust Center->Privacy Options->Uncheck "Warn before printing, saving or sending a file that contains tracked changes or comments"

does not work for me.

What works for me is:

msDoc.ActiveWindow.Close(WdSaveOptions.wdDoNotSaveChanges);

Comment: I wish I could up vote this a dozen times...was having an issue with a save dialog from a mail merge template, this totally saved my bacon

Comment: Except that this approach will not solve the problem in the question. The question wants to save the document. The approach found here will not save. The problem with the first line of code in this contribution is that it addresses the wrong Word object. It should address the Word Application, not a Document. See the accepted answer.