# Suppress Word save prompt about tracked changes

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

With help of a forum user, I was able to execute the following code flawlessly. 
However, when I wanted to save and close the word program, it prompts the following line:

**The document being saved contains tracked changes. Continue with save?**

Is there a way to suppress all prompts and warnings when saving the word doc using VBA?

My working code:

```
Sub DocSearchandReplace()

Dim wdApp As Object, wdDoc As Object
Set wdApp = CreateObject("word.application")
wdApp.Visible = True
Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open("P:\test.doc")

With wdDoc.Content.Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Text = "[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{4}"  
    .MatchWildcards = True 
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.Text = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A1").Text 
    .Execute Replace:=2, Forward:=True, Wrap:=1
End With

wdDoc.Save                    'it prompts and asks me whether continue to save
wdApp.ActiveDocument.PrintOut 'here again the same prompt when executing this line.
wdApp.Quit


Set wdApp = Nothing: Set wdDoc = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Have You tried `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` before and after with `=True` value?

Comment: The alert is raised on MSword itself, so I think you should try `wdApp .DisplayAlerts = wdAlertsNone`. I guess probably this will raise an error if you do not have a reference to MSword object library, so in that case try `wdApp .DisplayAlerts = 0` If you want to restore them later on, try `wdApp .DisplayAlerts = -1`. More info at https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.word.wdalertlevel?view=word-pia

Comment: Searching the error message brings up, for example, [How To Disable "The document being saved contains tracked changes" Word Dialog Using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5083220/how-to-disable-the- document-being-saved-contains-tracked-changes-word-dialog-u) Even though it's tagged C# the approach for VBA remains the same: `wdDoc.Options.WarnBeforeSavingPrintingSendingMarkup = false`

Comment: @CindyMeister Thank you, your method worked. However, it's not wdDoc.Option***, it has to be wdApp.Option****. I guess it's on the word application level.

Comment: @Teamothy I tried that one. It doesn't work on this particular prompt.

Comment: You're right, I simply copied from the "duplicate" and substituted your `Document` object for the one in that contribution. I've also corrected the Answer in the duplicate. Unfortunately, I'm no longer able to edit the comment...

Comment: @CindyMeister thank you so much. This syntax is crazy long. I don't know who came up with this idea. Anyway, it worked. :)

Comment: You mean the property name? Well, it's always a balance between something descriptive enough to be meaningful and conciseness :-) I'd say there's no mistaking what the option means...

Answer (score 0):

wdApp.Options.WarnBeforeSavingPrintingSendingMarkup = false